# Use a numeric value as string value in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, linked-data

Is possible to use somehow a numeric value as a string value in a SPARQL query?  For instance, consider the following RDF data, query, and desired result:

#### Knowledge base

```
@prefix gr:  <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>.
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>.

:o a gr:QuantitativeValueFloat;
     gr:hasMinValueFloat "1,0"^^xsd:float
     gr:hasMaxValueFloat "10,0"^^xsd:float
```

#### Query

```sql
PREFIX gr: <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>    
SELECT ?o ?v
WHERE {
  ?o a gr:QuantitativeValueFloat;
       gr:hasMinValueFloat ?vMin;
       gr:hasMaxValueFloat ?vMax.
  CONCAT((?vMin, ?vMax) as ?v)
}
```

#### Ideal Result

```
-----------------
| o  | v        | 
=================
| :o | 1,0-10,0 | 
-----------------
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In RDF, all literals have a lexical form that can be obtained with the [**str**](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str) function.  SPARQL also includes some shorthand for certain kinds of literals.  E.g., you can write **1** instead of **"1"^^xsd:integer**, but they're the same thing, and you can get **"1"** by doing either **str(1)** or **str("1"^^xsd:integer)**.  That means that you can do what you're trying to do with **str** and [**concat**](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-concat):

```sql
select ?xy where {
  values ?x { 1   }  #-- short for "1"^^xsd:integer
  values ?y { 2.5 }  #-- short for "2.5"^^xsd:decimal

  bind(concat(str(?x),"--",str(?y)) as ?xy)
}
```

```
------------
| xy       |
============
| "1--2.5" |
------------
```

This should work, even if the lexical form of the literals isn't legal for that datatype, as in you data where you have **"10,0"^^xd:float**, which should be **"10.0"^^xsd:float**, with a dot (**.**) rather than a comma (**,**).  (I realize that there are different conventions for the separator, but SPARQL uses the dot.)